# How to set the initial value of a select in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple app for displaying data. The state changes from a select. However I want the default select option to be united kingdom. Currently the option defaults to Afghanistan as it's the first in the alphabet.

```js
export default function CountrySelect() {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('GBR');
  const countries = useFetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries');

  if (!countries) return null;

  const countryArr = Object.entries(countries.countries).map(([key, value]) => {
    return {
      name: `${key}`,
      code: `${value}`
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Showing: {country}</h2>
      <select
        onChange={(event) => setCountry(event.target.value)}
        defaultValue={country}>
        {countryArr.map((country) => (
          <option value={country.code} key={country.name}>
            {country.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <Info url={`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${country}`}></Info>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To clarify the country state is 'GBR' and data from 'GBR' or United Kingdom is displayed. It's the  tag  which I'm having the issue with.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems to be HTML select and not react-select. There is no default value attribute to the default select. You can add the selected attribute to the required option here, like:

```
   const [selectedCountry, setCountry] = useState({ code: <Countrycode of UK>});
// ..
// ..
     <select
        onChange={(event) => setCountry(event.target.value)}
        {countryArr.map((country) => (
          <option selected={selectedCountry.code === country.code} value={country.code} key={country.name}>
            {country.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
```

Comment: That still has the option of 'Afghanistan' first. Even though the United Kingdom stats is show

Comment: @DGB Initialize `useState` with the object you're looking for instead of string 'GBR'. Updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use `defaultValue`, just add simple condions

```
const [countryState, setCountry] = useState('GBR');
{countryArr.map(country => {
      if (country.name !== countryState) {
        return (
          <option
            value={country.code}
            label={country.name}
            key={country.name}
          >
            {country.name}
          </option>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <option
            value={country.code}
            label={country.name}
            key={country.name}
            selected="selected"
          >
            {country.name}
          </option>
        );
      }
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the object property that you want to be the default option. Since you want the United Kingdom to be selected , set the **defaultValue** to the **code** that you get from the API.

Sandbox for reference : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-t1c2x

```
export default function CountrySelect() {
  const [selectedCountry, setCountry] = useState({
    code: "GB"
  });
  const countries = useFetch("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries", {});
  if (!countries) return null;
  const countryArr = Object.entries(countries.countries).map(([key, value]) => {
    return {
      name: `${key}`,
      code: `${value}`
    };
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={event => setCountry(event.target.value)}
        defaultValue={selectedCountry.code}
      >
        {countryArr.map(country => (
          <option value={country.code} key={country.name}>
            {country.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This successfully displays united kingdom as default however it doesn't display the data on mount and returns null. It only displays content once your changed options. Thanks though.